# BATCH: Creating multiple subfolders not working?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want a folder named 2015 in the subfolders in a directory...
eg. `C:/Clients/*/2015`
thus: `C:/Clients/John/2015`

This is what I tried, why does it not work? xD

```
FOR /d %A IN ("C:\Users\Jeanette\Documents\ClientSystem\*") DO mkdir "%A\2015"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to double % signs. Single % sign are only for command line parameters passed to the script.

Try this:

```
echo on
FOR /d %%A IN ("d:\tmp\*") DO mkdir "%%A\2015"
```